# How to keep quotes in arguments passed to a python script when using argparse, pexpect and docker?

Tags: python, bash, docker, argparse, pexpect

I'm making a python script, that wraps call to `docker run` by creating a child process with pexpect (pexpect is essential to me, because command might be interactive):

```py
import argparse
import pexpect


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("some_positional_argument")
parser.add_argument("command", nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)

args = parser.parse_args()

command = " ".join(args.command)
docker_run = f"docker run -it --rm ubuntu {command}"
print(f"docker_run: {docker_run}")

child = pexpect.spawn(docker_run)
child.interact()
child.close()
exit(child.exitstatus)
```

Problem is, when passing bash command with quotes to the `command` argument, python will interpret it as just a string value, so quotes will be gone:

```bash
python3 t.py foo bash -c 'echo hi'
docker_run: docker run -it --rm ubuntu bash -c echo hi
    # empty line here, because 'bash -c echo' was actually called inside the container
```

What is interesting to me, how docker solves this issue internally? Because `docker run` is similar CLI program, that will receive same unquoted `echo hi`. Example

```bash
docker run --rm -it ubuntu bash -c 'echo hi'
hi
```

works just fine.

I tried to look into docker cli source code:

- https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/06de1f8d2c56737ea06a547197a5ae3701aa5397/cli/command/container/run.go#L44
- https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/06de1f8d2c56737ea06a547197a5ae3701aa5397/cli/command/container/run.go#L108

parse function seemed promising:

- https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/06de1f8d2c56737ea06a547197a5ae3701aa5397/cli/command/container/opts.go#L324
- https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/06de1f8d2c56737ea06a547197a5ae3701aa5397/cli/command/container/opts.go#L402
- https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/06de1f8d2c56737ea06a547197a5ae3701aa5397/cli/command/container/opts.go#L632
- https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/06de1f8d2c56737ea06a547197a5ae3701aa5397/cli/command/container/opts.go#L716

but i didn't find any post processing (like adding quotes back) of the arguments.

Comment: The quotes are not part of the argument.  They just delimit the argument string.  The argument comes in to you as a simple string.  If need that string in quotes when you use it, then you need to add the quotes.  `f"...ubuntu '{command}'"`.  Just that easy.

Comment: > then you need to add the quotes

This solution will not work if the command contains escaped single quotes: 
```python
python3 t.py foo bash -c 'echo '\'hi with quotes''
docker_run: docker run -it --rm ubuntu 'bash -c echo 'hi with quotes'
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "bash -c echo hi": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

And I still can't understand, why plain `docker run` works without additional quoting.

Comment: If that's something that might happen, then you need to be smart about it and check for it.  That's EXACTLY what command line processors like bash have to do.

Comment: `argparse` just uses `sys.argv`, which should be a list of strings.  `bash` etc may processs quotes before passing the strings to python and `sys.argv`.

Comment: Python has a utility to give shell-like quote handling, `shlex`, `https://pymotw.com/2/shlex/`

Comment: hpaulj, thanks! I replaced `" ".join(args.command)` with `shlex.join(args.command)` and now everything works fine for any case.

You can post an answer if you want, so I'll make it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has a utility to give shell-like quote handling, shlex, https://pymotw.com/2/shlex/ (or officil python docs)

So replace

```
" ".join(args.command)
```

with

```
shlex.join(args.command)
```

to get properly quoted text.

Answer (score 0):

[`pexpect.spawn()`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#spawn-class) has a form where it takes a command and a list of arguments.  Use this.  **Never construct a command by concatenating strings together.**

```py
docker_args = ['run', '-it', '--rm', 'ubuntu'] + args.command
child = pexpect.spawn('docker', docker_args)
```

In your example, `bash -c 'echo hi'` is three shell words, `bash`, `-c`, and `echo hi`; the host shell will remove the single quotes before your program sees it (try printing out `args.command`).  Staying in the list-of-arguments form means you don't need to worry about what kind of quotes or escaping you might need to implement: you have four `docker` arguments plus the three-argument command and pass seven arguments to `docker`.

String manipulation here opens you up to a *shell injection attack*.  What happens if the command includes "special" shell characters, or single quotes?

```bash
./t.py foo \'word\' \; echo bar \> file
```

`pexpect` documents that it won't interpret this punctuation or run a shell at all, so you'll get potentially confusing results.  Of note `subprocess.call(shell=True)` *will* run a shell, and this would cause your program to run that `echo` command after the program exits.  Using the list syntax avoids this ambiguity: you have a list item containing `;` that is passed as an argument to the command and never interpreted as anything else.

Also consider whether the [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) can meet your needs. [`client.containers.run()`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.ContainerCollection.run) takes Python-native keyword arguments similar to `docker run`, but the corresponding [`container.attach_socket()`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.attach_socket) method to interact with the container's stdin/stdout can be trickier to use.